# Switching Inheritance Strategy from JOINED to SINGLE TABLE

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, jpa

Ive made a stupid error in a production system.

I chose JOINED strategy instead of SINGLE TABLE, and performance is seriously taking a hit.

I need to switch stragies and make appropriate changes to the schema, cant believe i screwed this up.

I would really appreciate and need some advice on how best to proceed.

Hibernate 3.5.6, JPA 2.0, SPRING 3.0

Comment: What is your problem? Do you understand the differences between database structures used for both strategies? Migration can be done with one `ALTER TABLE` and `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` per each inherited entity. That's it!

Comment: Hi Tomasz, thats exactly what i did in the end. I compared the two schema and made the appropriate changes. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Glad I could help. I promoted my comment to first-class answer so that it is easier to spot for newcomers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you understand the differences between database structures used for both strategies?

Migration can be done with one `ALTER TABLE` and `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` per each inherited entity. That's it!